# Difficult Radical Equation

Tags: radical-equations

I am stuck in the following radical equation 
$$
(4x-1)\sqrt{x^3+1}=2x^3+2x+1.
$$
**SOLUTION** I have tried based on the guidance of the commenters and I think that the following solution is rather simpler.
$$
(4x-1)\sqrt{x^3+1}=2x^3+2x+1
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
&\Leftrightarrow& 2(x^3+1)-\sqrt{x^3+1}-4x\sqrt{x^3+1}+2x+2\sqrt{x^3+1}-1=0\\
&\Leftrightarrow& \sqrt{x^3+1}(2\sqrt{x^3+1}-1)-2x(2\sqrt{x^3+1}-1)+2\sqrt{x^3+1}-1=0\\
&\Leftrightarrow&(2\sqrt{x^3+1}-1)(\sqrt{x^3+1}-2x+2)=0\\
&\Leftrightarrow&
2\sqrt{x^3+1}-1=0\quad\text{or}\quad
\sqrt{x^3+1}-2x+2=0\\
&\Leftrightarrow&
x=\sqrt[3]{-3/4}\quad\text{or}\quad
\begin{cases}
x\geq 1/2\\
x^3+1=4x^2-4x+1\\
\end{cases}\\
&\Leftrightarrow& x=\sqrt[3]{-3/4}\quad\text{or}\quad x=2.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: You’ll have to tell us what you’ve tried. Where do you get stuck? Is that the equation you started with or have you worked yourself into an algebra rut?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after squaring and factorizing we obtain $$-x \left( 4\,{x}^{3}+3 \right)  \left( x-2 \right) ^{2}=0$$
Can you solve this equation?

Answer (score 2):

$$(4x-1)\sqrt{x^3+1}=2x^3+2x+1.$$
$$\left((4x-1)\sqrt{x^3+1}\right)^2=\left(2x^3+2x+1\right)^2$$
$$16x^5+16x^2-8x^4-8x+x^3+1=4x^6+8x^4+4x^3+4x^2+4x+1$$
$$4x^6-16x^5+16x^4+3x^3-12x^2+12x=0$$
$$x\left(x-2\right)^2\left(\sqrt[3]{4}x+\sqrt[3]{3}\right)\left(4^{\frac{2}{3}}x^2-\sqrt[3]{12}x+3^{\frac{2}{3}}\right)=0$$

$$\tag1 x-2=0 \implies x=2$$
$$\tag2\sqrt[3]{4}x+\sqrt[3]{3}=0 \implies  x=-\sqrt[3]{\frac{3}{4}}$$
$$\tag3 4^{\frac{2}{3}}x^2-\sqrt[3]{12}x+3^{\frac{2}{3}}=0 \implies \nexists x\in \mathbb{R}$$
Therefore

> $$x_1=2,\quad  x_2=-\sqrt[3]{\frac{3}{4}}$$